# ¿Consultar datos especificos de mysql omitiendo otros en php?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes datos id, nombre, precio, categoría, descripción, pero quiero hacer una consulta de acuerdo a la categoría, por ejemplo, si selecciono la categoría de sillas solo imprima aquellas filas que tengan esa categoría en dicha columna.
Espero que no se repita el tema, he estado buscando en google cómo ordenar los datos, pero siempre me sale con el ordenamiento ascendente y descendente.
También he visto que alguna librería de javascript puede funcionar, como ajax o jquery.
Hazta ahora no tengo ningún problema con el código en la forma en la que lo estoy utilizando, ha funcionado, pero ahora quiero dar el siguiente paso, no quiero que aparezcan todos los productos que tengo en la tabla.
Este es el código:

```
           <?php
                include("conexion.php");

                $query = "SELECT * FROM productos";
                $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

                while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?>
           <?php echo base64_encode($row['product_img']);?>
           <?php echo $row['product_price']; ?>
           <?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>
           <?php echo $row['product_description']; ?>
```

[image: Resultado del código y de la consulta.]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si observan ahí se ven los diversos productos, quiero que al dar click en el de oficina me muestre los de oficina y si le doy click en sillas me muestre solo esos.
Gracias

Comment: primer punto añade por favor tu código, asi mismo menciona los errores que haz obtenido, segundo mencionas librerías como ajax; aclaración ajax no es una librería, finalmente añade tu esquema de tablas y un ejemplo del resultado que deseas obtener

Comment: te invito a hacer el recorrido para familiarizarte con el sitio [tour] así mismo te recomiendo leer como preguntar [ask] saludos y bienvenido

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta, edité la pregunta con la información.

Comment: Lo que dices al final  no hace otra cosa que confundir: *quiero que al dar click en el de oficina me muestre los de oficina y si le doy click en sillas me muestre solo esos* ... ¿a qué te refieres con eso?  ¿al dar click dónde? Si lo que quieres inicialmente es filtrar por una categoría determinada, tendrías que ponerle un `WHERE` a la consulta: `SELECT * FROM productos WHERE product_category='Silla oficina'`  ... Ya hablando de otro tema, es evidente que tus tablas necesitan un mejor diseño. Convendría que tengas una tabla `categoria` y que en `productos` enlaces por `id_categoria`.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera de hacerlo es que la consulta sql pida lo que realmente necesite y luego mostrar los elementos, es decir , construir la consulta de manera dinámica.

Puedes hacer que cada categoria sea un enlace en el HTML que llame al archivo PHP que va a realizar la consulta y le envíe la categoria a través de la url.

Ejemplo:

```
 <!--En tu HTML: -->
 <a href="tuArchivo.php?categoria=OFICINA">Oficina</a>
 <a href="tuArchivo.php?categoria=Sillas%Oficina">Sillas Oficina</a>
 <!--etc-->
```

Luego en tu PHP obtendrías el nombre de la categoría a través de la variable global $_GET para poder construir tu query.

En mi solución se utilizan datos externos para crear la consulta dinámicamente por lo que conlleva riesgo de inyeccion SQL.

Estos riesgos se pueden prevenir usando consultas preparadas. En este caso pondré el ejemplo de cómo hacerlo con la clase PDO de PHP.

```
//PHP
try {
    $conexionPDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', $usuario, $contraseña); 
    $conexionPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Error en la conexion ' . $e->getMessage());
}

 $stmt = $conexionPDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE product_category = :categoria");
 $stmt->bindParam(':categoria', $_GET['categoria']);
 $stmt->execute();

 while ($row = $stmt>fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      echo base64_encode($row['product_img']);
      echo $row['product_price']; 
      echo $row['product_name']; 
      echo $row['product_description'];
 }
 $stmt=null;
 $conexionPDO=null;
```

**Mirate la clase PDO de PHP:** http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php

**E información acerca de la inyección SQL en PHP:** https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL#PHP

**Aqui se habla largo y tendido también sobre la inyección sql**
[Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Pero... tu respuesta es algo contradictoria. Hablas de la inyección SQL y al mismo tiempo la fomentas escribiendo consultas como esta: `SELECT * FROM productos WHERE product_category = $_GET['categoria'];` ¿? ¿No es esta una forma de desorientar, y de aportar soluciones basadas en una mala y peligrosa práctica?

Comment: No la fomento , usaba la consulta tal y como supongo que la usaría el autor de la pregunta para que pudiera probar mi solución en su código ya que no estaba usando consultas preparadas  y advirtiéndole de los riesgos que conlleva. @A.Cedano

Comment: Añadiré el código de cómo sería la consulta preparada a mi respuesta @A.Cedano

Comment: Su consulta no tiene ningún riesgo de inyección, porque es una consulta en la que no intervienen datos externos, por lo tanto se puede ejecutar con `query` sin ningún tipo de problema. Pero al tú incluir la variable `$_GET['categoria']` ya debes prevenir contra inyección, explicando lo que es en vez de escribir la consulta vulnerable que has escrito. Para mi eso es desorientar al OP y enseñar malas prácticas. Además ¿por qué `$_GET['categoria']`, de dónde sale eso? Ni siquiera se sabe si el OP tiene algo para recoger las categorías...

Comment: Bueno , he tratado de aportar una solución , si , una solución en la que intervienen datos externos y  he apuntado lo que se necesita para aplicar correctamente mi solución y dejando las fuentes donde puede ampliar su conocimiento , no se por que eso es desorientar y enseñar malas practicas. @A.Cedano

Comment: Serux mis comentarios son con la intención de que mejores la respuesta, nada más. Cuando tú enseñas a ejecutar una consulta como esta: `SELECT * FROM productos WHERE product_category = $_GET['categoria'];` tú estás enseñando no solamente malas prácticas, sino también prácticas peligrosas, por el riesgo de la inyección SQL.

Comment: De acuerdo , voy a intentar mejorarla sustituyendo esa consulta por una preparada. Creo que tienes razon en que es un ejemplo peligroso @A.Cedano

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta , no soy ningún experto en PHP solo trato de ayudar con los pocos conocimientos que tengo , te agradecería que le echaras un vistazo e incluso la editaras si puedes si consideras que hay algo mejorable @A.Cedano

Comment: La consulta está bien ahora Serux. Saludos y disculpa mi insistencia.

Comment: Ni te disculpes , entendí que era importante mejorar la respuesta , saludos @A.Cedano

Answer (score 0):

Si, después de todo lo solucioné con

```
 SELECT * FROM productos WHERE product_category = 'OFICINA'
```

pero no usé PDO porque realmente no lo entiendo, usé mysqli